# Multiple approval from editors before publishing?

Tags: posts, content

I would like to have more than 1 editor approve a post before it can be published. Is their anything that does this out of the box or will I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

That's going to require a plugin. Best to roll your own as I couldn't find an existing plugin for it that was up to date. Here's the out of date one I found as it might help to look over its code when building your own: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-approvals/

Comment: Thanks thats a step in the right direction. Hopefully someone else has found something, but this helps a lot thanks.